# Pagination adds product to cart Woo-Commerce

Tags: theme-development, pagination, woocommerce-offtopic

In my WordPress Woo-Commerce theme when a product is added to cart from shop page its added into the cart with a url e.g `/shop/page/3/?add-to-cart=149` and when I switch to another page using pagination, It is unable to remove the `?add-to-cart=149` from the url and on visit to next or previous page and adds the same product again. for navigation I am using a custom function.

```
function custom_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;

    $pages = paginate_links( array(
            'base'         =>  esc_url_raw( str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', remove_query_arg( 'add-to-cart', get_pagenum_link( 999999999, false ) ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'prev_next' => false,
            'type'  => 'array',
            'prev_next'   => TRUE,
            'prev_text'    => __('«'),
            'next_text'    => __('»'),
        ) );
        if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
            $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
            echo '<ul class="pagination">';
            foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                    echo "<li>$page</li>";
            }
           echo '</ul>';
        }
}
```

It had to handle it in the base argument but its not doing so.

Answer (score -1):

Paste this code into your `functions.php` and it will be solved.

```
add_action('add_to_cart_redirect', 'resolve_dupes_add_to_cart_redirect');
function resolve_dupes_add_to_cart_redirect($url = false) {
     if(!empty($url)) { return $url; } 

     return get_bloginfo('wpurl').add_query_arg(array(), remove_query_arg('add-to-cart'));
}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code and explain why does it solve the problem.

Comment: -1 No explanation to code, plus no acknowledgement to where this was actually copied (yes, copied) from. Plus it doesn't work for a multisite setup that uses directories.